# ASP.NET - Still getting flicker despite using UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have put several controls into an UpdatePanel. When I press the button inside the update panel there's no progress bar on the bottom status bar and there's no typical click sound that occurs during a normal postback. But the page still flickers to the top and I cannot see the validation errors. Could it be because I have a DataGrid on the update panel. I heard DataGrid and Updatepanel don't work well together.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any validation controls?  I tend to add Validation controls but forget to assign the ErrorMessage text which often cuases me ponder why something isn't working.

Comment: I am. But all the validation controls have their error messages and all those validations are bound to a ValidationSummary